# Find rows containing the Regex [:digit:]

Tags: mysql

I want to create a regex to find all rows containing a number between square brackets **[1]**

I've used this query:

`` SELECT * FROM `Landscapes` WHERE `Description` REGEXP "\[(.*?)\]" ``

But it returns all the rows.

Also

`` SELECT * FROM `Landscapes` WHERE `Description` REGEXP "\\[(.*?)\\]" ``

Says it's an invalid regex.

I want to start with the goal of finding the Regex, then move on to the goal of removing it.

**P.S:** The Regex works in C#. So the Regex is right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.*?` part in the `\\[(.*?)\\]` should match everything in every regex engine. so it's logical you get every records in MySQL.

Most likely you are looking for regex pattern `\\[[0-9]+\\]`

**Query**

```
SELECT * FROM `Landscapes` WHERE `Description` REGEXP "\\[[0-9]+\\]"
```

**Result**

```
| Description      |
| ---------------- |
| lurom ipsum [1]  |
| lurom ipsum [11] |
| lurom ipsum [2]  |
| lurom ipsum [22] |
```

see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/c1a75BixR8tGm4S6exLTen/0)

Comment: That did work. Stupidly enough. Why would it work in one engine and not the other? I thought Regex is a unified language.

Comment: *"Why would it work in one engine and not the other? I thought Regex is a unified language. "* @AhmadSattout Not sure if regex has a ANSI/ISO standard or a RFC for that matter but SQL for example has a standard language where database vendors add or change things,